# What is the command/configuration to run NodeJS/Express app as a daemon?

Tags: mean-stack, mean.io

In SSH if I run:

```
$ node server
```

My web app works fine until I close the SSH session. What is the command or configuration needed so that it runs all the time without an active SSH session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run it like:

```
nohup node server
```

Or you can install forever.

```
npm -g install forever
forever start server
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple nodejs, you can use `pm2` to manage them.

Or, use screen or tmux to keep the nodejs running while detach the session.